# Searching files to Ntfs

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am newbie in Pinvoke. I want get mft after I find root when I can access directories.
I want to use `DeviceIoControl` such as the code below:

```
BOOL DeviceIoControl(
   (HANDLE) hDevice,           // handle to device
   FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA, // dwIoControlCode
   NULL,                       // lpInBuffer
   0,                          // nInBufferSize
   (LPVOID) lpOutBuffer,       // output buffer
   (DWORD) nOutBufferSize,     // size of output buffer
   (LPDWORD) lpBytesReturned,  // number of bytes returned
   (LPOVERLAPPED) lpOverlapped // OVERLAPPED structure
   );
```

I don't known what value of `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364569.aspx) lists `WinIoCtl.h` as being the relevant header. When we look there at the macro declaration we see:

```
#define FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA \
    CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM, 25, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

Which leaves us with a little work to do. The lazy way to do this is to write a program to emit the value:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    DWORD code = FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA;
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << code;
    return 0;
}
```

And this outputs our desired value:

```
0x00090064
```

Comment: I could just have given you the number, but I thought it more helpful to explain how to get hold of it for yourself. Then you can find out any other FSCTL code values that you may need.